# how to repeat a block of code in bigquery for multiple columns?

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, subquery, aggregate

I would like to repeat a block of code with a complex operation (defined in a subquery) for many columns in bigquery. I cannot find a better way than copy and paste the same code block for each  column name multiple times. Just for an example, same operation for three different columns:

```
SELECT 
    SQRT(a_name1 + b_name1) AS result_name1,
    SQRT(a_name2 + b_name2) AS result_name2,
    SQRT(a_name3 + b_name3) AS result_name3
FROM
(
SELECT
  SUM(name1_col1 + name1_col2 / name1_col3) / SUM(name1_col1)  AS a_name1,
  SUM(name1_col1 * name1_col2 + name1_col3) / SUM(name1_col2) AS b_name1,

  SUM(name2_col1 + name2_col2 / name2_col3) / SUM(name2_col1) AS a_name2,
  SUM(name2_col1 * name2_col2 + name2_col3) / SUM(name2_col2) AS b_name2,

  SUM(name3_col1 + name3_col2 / name3_col3) / SUM(name3_col1)  AS a_name3,
  SUM(name3_col1 * name3_col2 + name3_col3) / SUM(name3_col2) AS b_name3
FROM data
)
```

where data is like

```
name1_col1 | name1_col2 | name1_col3 | name2_col1 | name2_col2 | name2_col3 | name3_col1 | name3_col2 | name3_col3 |
     1     |        2   |     3.1    |     1.2    |    -0.4    |   0.3      |    2       |    3       |     3.4    |
...
```

As there are aggregation operations it seems it's not possible to define a UDF function.

I have looked online and in other questions, but I have not been able to find any relevant answer.

Could you please help me?

Comment: That's often addressed by a design change.  Instead of operating across columns of a row, you could perform that operation down rows of one column.  There are costs/benefits to both approaches.  Sometimes one approach doesn't address all your issues.

Comment: The operation I would like to use combine values from several columns, so it's not clear to me how to perform the operation down rows first

Comment: As a starting point, feat1_val1, feat1_val2, and feat1_val3 are functionally dependent on featN, where N = 1.  We could have a row for each featN containing val1, val2, val3, allowing a direct calculation grouped by featN.  There's some detail missing in the question, so it's tough to understand the full context.

Comment: let me modify the names of the columns, perhaps the question will be more clear

Comment: Right.  This implementation with nameN, where N is the key into other columns of the same row, tends to be a problem.  When normalizing, you want the non-key columns to be functionally dependent on the entire primary key.  In this case, the name1_colN columns are dependent on name1, not the primary key.  By normalizing those cases, you are able to perform your calculation over all nameN's at once, since the related values for each N are in separate rows, as mentioned above.

Comment: Hi @Galuoises, Did above comment help you in resolving the issue?

Comment: I am not sure. Perhaps an example would clarify it

Answer (score 0):

If possible Create view with this query and use view for your operation just using column names.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).